# How to return response of a request within a promise?

Tags: javascript

I have a code structure like this:

```js
function f1() {
  return f2().then(function(res2) {
    var arr = res2;
    var a = "default";
    arr.forEach(function(element) {

      if (element.condition) {
        ...
      } 
      else {
        f3().then(function(res3) {
          a = res3;
          });
      }
    };
    return [arr, a];
  });
};

f1().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result[0]);
  console.log(result[1]);
  });
```

result[0] (array) has actual value of array, however, result[1] (a) is "default". 
How should I modify the code above to get the actual value of 'a'?

Comment: can you show the `f2` method please?

Comment: Looks like `element.condition` is never falsey?

Comment: If `a` is set asynchronously from a second call (which seems like it does), you can't do it in this fashion. You'll need to use `Promise.all` to wait on the result of all of the async operations done on `arr`.

Comment: @JoeyGough I edited the code to make it clearer. f2 function returns the response of the first fetch request, f3 function returns the response of the second fetch request

Comment: @ChrisG no, it does get false at some moment. If I print value of 'a' in each iteration, the result looks like 'default', 'default', 'default', 'default', 'actual_value', 'actual_value'... still it returns 'default'

Comment: @ChrisGabler The basic idea is to use `Promise.all()` instead of `arr.forEach`, since you have asynchronous operations in there.